# RealURL not working on migrated TYPO3 site

Tags: typo3, realurl

I recently helped a client move their TYPO3 site to a new hosting provider. I did not design or build the site, nor have I any experience with TYPO3 (I work with Wordpress as a CMS mainly).

While everything transferred okay, files and database etc the URLs to any of the pages aren't found.

The site is here: https://feixandmerlin.com

If you click on About Us in the left nav for example, the page isn't found. However I can view it from the backend preview here: https://feixandmerlin.com/index.php?id=6 This is the same for all of the pages on the site.

I can't work out how to relink it all together!

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there's problem with `mod_rewrite` directive on new server. RealURL generates "*speaking urls*" correctly anyway server isn't able to translate it back to `index.php?id=123`. Two things to check:

1. Make sure that you copied `.htaccess` file too, often default FTP clients hides the hidden files (these starting with dot) so it's easy to forget this.
2. Make sure that Apache on new machine has `mod_rewrite` enabled.

If you need the support from the server's admin for configuring Apache, show him/her this answer and especially [**this link**](http://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/testing).

Answer (score 1):

Need to check this all points :

1) Enable mod-rewrite in server. RealUrl needed server **rewrite mode ON**

2) Make Rewrite Base ON From **.htacess** file.

3) Clear the RealUrl Cache. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0744lh1i6d

4) This site is migration from old to new. We need to follow last step of migration truncate the **cf_*** table from database manually.

I hope the problem belongs to either mod_rewrite or realurl cache.

There is alternative of realurl which do same thing convert the url from id to pages.

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cooluri